# What does the idiom "что уж там" mean?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения, выражения, идиомы

I am very puzzled by the idiom "**что уж там**" and its sister "**чего уж там**". Let me show you a few sentences:

> (1) Давайте везде курить, **что уж там**, детям в лицо: депутат Госдумы ([Source](https://regnum.ru/news/polit/2667285.html))
>
> (2) Да **что уж там**, благодаря им выросли экономики целой полдюжины стран. ([Source](https://www.gazeta.ru/culture/2019/05/20/a_12366199.shtml))
>
> (3) И мне линк давайте, **что уж там**. ([Source](https://habr.com/ru/users/oowl/comments/page4/?mobile=no))
>
> (4) Самокопание, уверенность в себе и – **чего уж там** – правильное место и правильное время важны наравне с талантом. ([Source](https://impactlab.media/2019/01/10/po-ponyatiyam-8-zhiznennyih-istin-kotoryim-nas-uchit-chernoe-zerkalo))
>
> (5) Он вошел с ключом огромным,
>
> Намекнул с порога сам:
>
> – Разуваться? – так нескромно.
>
> – Раздевайся, **что уж там**. ([Source](http://www.hohmodrom.ru/project.php?prid=48338))

My question: What is the meaning of "**что уж там**" and "**чего уж там**" when they're used as idioms as in Examples (1)-(5) above?

I tried to do my own research, but got conflicting results. For example, Reverso Context offers a variety of English translations, e.g., "anyway," "even," "come on." I feel that such translations don't hit the bullseye and don't capture the precise meaning of the idiom, but I'm at a loss as to exactly what the precise meaning is. I humbly hope that native Russian speakers will be able to kindly help a confused Japanese student understand this idiom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1. Давайте везде курить, что уж там, детям в лицо: депутат Госдумы.

Here "что уж там" is very close to "whatever".

---

> 2. Да что уж там, благодаря им выросли экономики целой полдюжины стран.

Here, it's close to "let's be honest".

---

> 3. И мне линк давайте, что уж там.

Here it can be translated as - "Aaaaah, whaveter, give me the link" or "Aw, screw it, give me the link".

---

> 4. Самокопание, уверенность в себе и – чего уж там – правильное место и правильное время важны наравне с талантом.

Here, it's close to "let's be honest here".

---

> 5. Раздевайся, что уж там.

This is sort of like "to hell with all this etiquette — get naked!".

One might ask how on Earth this can mean so many different things. The answer is pretty simple - "что уж там"/"чего уж там" is a short form of "что уж там" plus some verb. Let's revisit all the examples you provided. We can rewrite them using the following forms:

1. чего уж там стесняться
2. да что уж там скрывать
3. что уж там выпендриваться
4. чего уж там умалчивать
5. раздевайся, чего уж там кокетничать

See? Now it all makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it makes sense now. So it seems I have to guess the missing verb each time :)

Comment: @Mitsuko you've basically covered all the main cases :) nice research by the way )

Comment: What an outstanding and informative answer. You outdid yourself!

Answer (score 3):

You can think of it as "что уж там **думать**...", meaning that further reflection about the issue in question is pointless. There *is* no exact translation, of course, and people with different emotional attitudes will translate it differently in a generic context. This grammatical construction, "что + infinitive", meaning that performing the action expressed by the infinitive is undesirable, is rather advanced since it isn't something you hear every day.

Another example: "что головой трясти, работать пора" — "enough nodding your head — it's time to get to work". It can be understood as an ellipsis in and of itself: "что **толку** головой трясти".

"Уж" is close to "уже" in meaning, as it refers to a situation that has changed in one's mind and which is now thought of differently. For example: "я уж не знаю" — "now, I can't say anything at all". "Там" means just "there", that is far enough in the mental space, which results in describing someone who does not want to give much thought to something: "Я послал туда несколько отрядов, там восемь или десять" — "I sent a few groups there — I don't know... maybe eight or ten".

Answer (score 3):

Оно отражает то, что следующая за ним вещь является усиленной версией предшествующей. При этом довольно часто будет приводиться прям доведённая до крайности или до абсурда.

В большинстве случаев можно перевести как "а ещё" (and/but also/even) или "не задумываясь" (don't think/care/bother). Вариант, который мне нравится больше других, я выделил курсивом.

> Давайте везде курить, что уж там, детям в лицо

*Let's smoke everywhere and even [blow the smoke] in children's faces.*

Let's smoke everywhere and [blow the smoke] in children's faces without bothering yourself.

> Да что уж там, благодаря им выросли экономики целой полдюжины стран.

And also because of them, the economies of a whole half a dozen counties have gone up.

> И мне линк давайте, что уж там.

And give me the link, also. (If they gave it to multiple people and the asker wants a link, too.)

Don't bother, give me the link. (Seems less suitable for this phrase, but in general this type of usage is possible in "Да что уж там, дайте ссылку".)

*Give me the link, too.*

> Самокопание, уверенность в себе и – чего уж там – правильное место и правильное время важны наравне с талантом. (Source)

Self-digging, self-confidence and even the right place and the right time are just as important as talent.

> Он вошел с ключом огромным,
> Намекнул с порога сам:
> – Разуваться? – так нескромно.
> – Раздевайся, что уж там.

[You can not only take off you shoes] — you even can take off your clothes.

Don't think [about anything], just strip.

Just strip.

- *Take off my shoes?*
- *Everything.*

Answer (score 2):

It means "let's not restrict ourselves", "let's go all the way", "let's be honest/frank/direct/unrestricted"

Answer (score 1):

1. "Пофигу" (переносный смысл, сатира)
2. Да, "можно сказать" или "благодаря им..."
3. "Ну ладно" или "хорошо, уговорили"
4. "Ещё в чем-либо", выражает незнание чего-либо или не хотение разбираться (способ сокращения)
5. "нечего стыдиться"

Answer (score 1):

The linguistic term for this phenomenon is called [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) - "omission of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements".

As I think of this, different other expression come to my mind:

```
где уж мне (тебе и т.д.)
куда уж нам (вам и т.д.)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this to be an idiom either. It's just increasing the meaning of the phraze and to be translated in context. It's not used that often, in books yes, but not in everyday life. It can be easily said without там, just чего уже(раз всем дали), дайте и мне ссылку или раздевайся, чего уже (ждать) so as it can be seen it's like missing some continuation of a phraze is being replaced by чего уж там.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute "что уж там" with a shorter version "чeго там", when you want to impart it with the meaning "not a big deal" or "forget it".

This is illustrated, e.g., by the first dialogue of Khan Edigu and the Prince of Zvenigorod in the movie "Andrei Rublev", see frame 1:26:40 in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkCeEYuMyOY

-- Прости, опоздал.

-- А, чего там…

/Implies: "Come on, not a big deal."/

Answer (score 0):

This idiom is incompleted phrase "чего уж там стеснятся!" ("if so - let's not be ashamed of it!" - smth like that)

Comment: please add answer that adds something new to the answer provided.